# Is it possible to display Google Analytics reporting interface in an IFRAME?

Tags: iframe, google-analytics

Has anyone had much luck in embedding the Google Analytics reporting interface in an IFRAME?

We'd like to add an "Analytics" tab to our CMS which displays the Google Analytics for each specific page.  So, the user could view a page in the CMS, and see the analytics for that page right in the interface.

We have everything worked out, and we're bringing up the correct URL in the IFRAME.  We get the Google login page, but when we log in, Google "busts" the IFRAME and loads the analytics page in the full window.

Is there anyway to keep Google Analytics reporting interface in an IFRAME?

Answer (score 2):

Why not use the [Google Analytics Data Export API](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataDeveloperGuide.html) to access the data and build your own reports?

Comment: "build your own reports" -- lots of work involved with that statement. The end users are used to the built-in GA interface and their reports.  They just want to be able to browse them in the context of a page in the CMS without a separate browser window.

Comment: Then you're pretty much at the mercy of the creators of the Analytics site then, which may not want someone to embed their site in an iframe as you've found

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to IFRAME Google Analytics.
A work around to this is to build a chrome extension and append your codes/page into analytics site via content_scripts to put some "toolbar" on top or to do some modifications you want.

This is what I'm doing at the moment, sorry that I couldn't share the chrome extension code at the moment.